# Why won't this work; opencv Mat_<float>

Tags: c++, eclipse, opencv, pattern-recognition

I can't seem to get this to work. I'm trying to get the pixel value of an image but first need to change the color of the image, but since I cannot use int or just Mat because the values are not whole numbers, I have to use `<float>` and because of that errors pop up when I try to run this on the cmd.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    Mat img = imread(argv[1]);
    ofstream myfile;

    Mat_<float> MatBlue = img;
        int rows1 = MatBlue.rows;
        int cols1 = MatBlue.cols;
        for(int x = 0; x < cols1; x++) {
            for(int y = 0; y < rows1; y++) {
                float val = MatBlue.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[1];
                MatBlue.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0] = val + 1;

            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal, i.e. type conversion, use `cv::Mat::convertTo`.

Example: `img.convertTo(MatBlue, CV_32F)` or `img.convertTo(MatBlue, CV_32F, 1.0/255.0)` (to have values normalized between 0 and 1).

You are mixing char and float pointer types in your code.